# How to know what arguments have to be passed to the NodeJS call back functions?

Tags: node.js, callback

I have got a code like

```
var dns = require('dns');

dns.resolve4('www.google.com', function (err, addresses) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('addresses: ' + JSON.stringify(addresses));
});
```

How do we got the err, addresses arguments? what all other arguments can i pass?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should have a look API https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_resolve4_hostname_callback . According API, first arguments will be error nd second one will be array of IP4 addresses

Answer (score 1):

> Callback as for standard it takes the first argument as `error` and second argument as `result`

Let's understand with simple example

```
/**
 * [executeRequest description]
 * @param  {[type]}   params   [params which need to pass]
 * @param  {[type]}   body     [body  which need to pass]
 * @param  {Function} callback [a callback function which finally executed after manipulation]
 * @return {[type]}            [callback with error or success]
 */
function executeRequest(params,body,callback){
//Execute some task here. it depends what this function does
 pass error in callback if get error like this
 callback(err);

 pass result if success
 callback(null,result);
}
```

---

Now call this function which needs to pass `params, body and callback`

```
executeRequest(params,body,function(err,result){
//Always the first argument of callback function is err and second argument is success 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on function specification, ask to google :

npm dns resolve4

[NPM doc](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html)

[resolve4](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#apicontent)

Only two arguments, err and address